# handle webform usercontrol load event from within the control code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, event-handling

The subject line says it all. I am not talking about the event handler of the instance of the usercontrol that we put in an aspx page. I am referring to the load event handler from within the code behind of the usercontrol class itself. Just like we have `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}` event handler of a page. What is the method signature of a user control event handler?

Thanks.

Comment: it's called `Page_Load` as well

Comment: Thanks.I was looking at this chart. https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png It shows a separate Load event for control that occurs after the page Load event.